# App ads_management permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-permissions

Question: Is it possible for application which associated with business manager to obtain ads_management permissions and make server-to-server calls using appId|appSecret as access token. 
If yes then what are the correct steps to obtain those permissions for an app?
If no then is there a way to get access token for the user with such permissions which never expires?

Details: As stated in FB documentation, in order to make server-to-server requests without need to obtain and refresh access tokens we may use pair of app Id and app secret in form of appId|appSecret.

Our application now has the following permissions:
- email
- public_profile
- user_friends

In order to make calls to Ads API our application has to have ads_management permissions. Currently we make calls to Ads API through user-level access token and this is not preferable for us as this token requires refreshes which must be done manually using browser interaction (we can't obtain access token programmatically)

Answer (score 5):

You may be confusing App Access Tokens (which allow you to make calls on behalf of the app itself) with permissions (which an individual user grants you to act on their behalf) - you'll always need a user token to update things belonging to a user.

A user, who's an admin of the ad account you want to manage, needs to grant your app `ads_management` permission - once they've done that, the OAuth flow gives you an access token to make API calls on their behalf, and that token doesn't expire for up to 60 days (after which point they need to come back to your site/app while logged into Facebook for you to get an updated token)

In the context of Business Manager, that user must be someone that has access via Business Manager to the assets (ad acccounts and pages) you want to update via the API

If your app has Standard access to the Ads API, you can also use 'System Users' to make sessionless API calls to update the assets of the business: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/v2.2

More info about login here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/chapter-1-Setup-and-Authentication

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens